# At what point does the fragment in a container change after i call the commit method?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to edit data in a fragment from the activity. I have called the fragment manager to replace the fragment in the container to a new fragment, but when I try to cast the fragment in the container to the new type, i get an error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myCompany.myApp.Fragment2 cannot be
>   cast to com.myCompany.myApp.Fragment1.

Here is my code in the activity

```
public void respond(Transaction.Type type, String title, Double amount, String description) {
        add_edit_transaction fragment = new add_edit_transaction();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainContent,fragment).commit();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Replaced!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        add_edit_transaction frag= (add_edit_transaction)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.mainContent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The commit does not happen immediately; it will be scheduled as work on the main thread to be done the next time that thread is ready.

If you need a transaction to happen immediately you can force it by calling FragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()